# Relatively to each other — less awkward word?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions, synonyms

I'm rating the performance of things in different dimensions on a scale, e.g. `[--, -, 0, +, ++]`. This ranking only describes the relative performance in one dimension, without referring to other things in the outside world or one of the other dimensions.

If I say,

> ... the performance of the things in the dimensions is rated
>   relatively.

, I'm not sure that this concept gets conveyed to the reader correctly.

Is there a more fitting word to describe the confinedness of the ratings?

Comment: Please add the rest of that sentence, relative to _what_?

Comment: Exactly that is my problem, relatively to itself, or more precisely, relatively to the other members in the group of things. So it's a reflexive "relative".

Comment: *the performance of **each of the** things in the dimensions is rated relative **to the others**.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to restrict comparisons to members of a particular set, and have no comparison outside that set. For example, you want to compare *your company's* products A and B and not to consider any other company's similar products.

> The performance of the things is compared against each other

You could add "without reference to anything else" to make it perfectly explicit.

Unfortunately I can't find a dictionary reference to explain ***against each other,*** although the phrase is used in nearly forty definitions in OED. However the use of *each other* does nicely match your description as "reflexive relative".

Answer (score 0):

This is very hard to answer without more context. The constrict you are using in your example is quite clumsy, could you change it to one of

> The table below shows the relative performance of the items.
>
> Performance scores are given relative to one another.

Answer (score -1):

It's hard to generalize without more concrete details, but something like:

> ...the performance of the things are contrasted/compared in the dimension of ...

For example:

> The performances of the rockets are compared [only] in terms of relative acceleration.